# Error VBA in word code 4605 "can't use SetWidth because the object references the end of a table row."

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to use a macro in Word in order to adjust the width of a table. But I can't get it to work. When I use the `SetWidth` method on `Selection.Columns` in my macro, an error is thrown.

I use a macro that was working previously, but now it doesn't want to do this width adjustment. I already tried to use a variety of other solution like use `width` or `preferredWidth` instead of `setWidth`. I also tried executing that code earlier and it works fine.

This is the code supposed to adjust the column width.

```
Selection.GoTo what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="proj1_cat1_j"
    Selection.Columns.SetWidth ColumnWidth:=105, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustFirstColumn
```

Moreover, the table is a big one. And I'm accessing the first cell of one column in order to adjust it. There is nothing that's attached to that table (like text on the right or something else)

The expected result is simply the table with the column adjusted. But instead I get an error code 4605 saying that I can't use the `setWidth` method because it's referencing the end of a table row.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong ?

PS : I can't share more of the macro, it's so big it's difficult to know which parts are important to share or not.

Comment: The `SetWidth` line of code worked fine for me in a quick test. So questions: 1) Which version of Word? 2) Are you absolutely certain the bookmark is *in a table cell*?  I get a similar (not exactly the same) error message if the Selection is at the end of a table row... 3) What do you mean by "tab" ("the tab is a big tab")? I would interpret this as "tab stop" or dialog box tab... Do you mean table?

Comment: 1) Word version 1808 
2) I am completely positive it is in a table cell. When the goTo line is executed, I see the cursor exactly at the position of the bookmark, in the cell.
3) Yes I meant table, the table is 50rows by 7 columns

I found out 2 more things : 
First it seems to happen only in a certain case, and the bookmark is exactly at the top of the table. 
Second, I was able to temporarily bypass the problem by accessing the PreferredWidth property.
But it doesn't work as well as I want it too..

Comment: Word version 2016 

I actually translated it from french to be honest... I didn't find a similar error in English. But I did some more research in my code, and it seems like some times, I can't access the width property..

Comment: OK, I've corrected the error message in the title for you, since it seems more logical and I did see it *when Selection is outside a table cell*...

Comment: The VBA Editor has an "Immediate Window", which you go to by pressing Ctrl+G (once it's visible you can also simply click in it). The next time your code errors due to a "width" issue, type this in the Immediate Window then press Enter: `?Selection.Information(wdAtEndOfRowMarker)` If you see `True` then the selection is outside a table cell, at the end of a row. (If you're not seeing the little "sunshine" symbols in the table cells and at the end of a row, click the "backwards P" button in the Home tab of the Ribbon to display non-printing characters, and show the table gridlines.)

Comment: I just had the error (it didn't crash the macro but I saw Err going to 4605) and I tried your code, for information on the Selection. And the value returned was False, not true..

Comment: OK... In that case we need a [mcve]. Try, in a new document, to create a table with a bookmark that can trigger the problem (you mentioned "at the top of a table?). Put together a macro with the minimal amount of code to trigger the error. Then *explain in the question* how we can reproduce this and include the macro. It may have something to do with how the bookmark is created...

Comment: I will try to do that, but I'm not sure I'll have the time today. I'll come back with more information as soon as I can. Thanks anyway for your help !